# How to "auto-build" and load different CSS stylesheet files when running a 'development' and 'production' mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, load

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 and I would like to *auto*-build and load different CSS stylesheet files depending on if I am running my application in the `development` or in the `production` mode.

I would like to auto-"minimize" CSS files for performance reasons and to load those related "minimized" files *because* I do not want to show to the "public audience" the content of my *comments* present in my CSS file (note: users can access theme, for example, by using the FireBug plugin for the Mozilla Firefox browser). I would like to do that also for javascript files.

**How can I do that?**

P.S.: I am planning to switch to the Ruby on Rails v3.1...

Answer (score 7):

In your layout you probably have something like:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "production.css" %>
```

Just add another stylesheet there but wrap it in a conditional that checks the rails environment.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "development.css" if Rails.env.production? %>
```

Comment: Thanks much for this, @Nathan Manousos! I was briefly confused by a namespacing issue in my code base but it's much better now. This should mitigate confusion for us.

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 3.0 there are many plugins to minify your css and javascript.

I use `smurf`.

```
gem "smurf"
```

Part of the process of minification is that it removes comments.

In Rails 3.1 production will `uglify` your javascript, so comments should be removed by default.

But if you insist on using a different stylesheet, take a look at the other answer.